# Cucumber glue configuration when there are two dependency with the same package path

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I have two dependency in my project which contain classes with the same name and the same path. But when I put package path into the glue I get a conflict between those two packages.

Is there a way to configure glue to access only one of the dependencies?

Comment: If I understand correctly you have two conflicting classes in your classpath (all classes you load), only one will be loaded and the JVM will choose which one, Cucumber has no way to interact at this level.

Comment: Why do you have two dependencies with the same package name and class name? What do you mean by "conflict between those two packages"? What do you expect to get (what would be the criteria of picking one dependency instead of another) ?

Comment: Yes,

I have setup like this
        <dependency>
            <groupId>gr1</groupId>
            <artifactId>atr1</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>gr2</groupId>
            <artifactId>atr3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Each of this dependency has a package with identical name and path. I wish to use in glue only package from the first dependency. Is it possible to configure?